# Redis sentinel high availibility - error on running sentinel.conf

Tags: redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

I am configuring Redis sentinel on 3 nodes. I am able to execute redis.conf with all the master slave configuration. Having issue to figure out what is causing sentinel.conf to error out. This is the error I am getting on executing `cd src/ && redis-server ../sentinel.conf — sentinel &`

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 84
>>> 'sentinel monitor mymaster 3.122.x.x 6379 2'
sentinel directive while not in sentinel mode
```

Thanks for the help.